# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011: Report Viewer Print Scale

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, reportviewer, reportbuilder

I've created a report with **MS SQL Server Report Builder**. When I export a PDF from the Report Viewer, I can set the scale to 100% in **Acrobat Reader** and it will print perfectly. But when I print it directly from the **CRM Report Viewer**, every element will scale down.

In the picture you can see two variants. In the background is the PDF Version and in the front is the CRM Report Viewer Version.

Here is the print Problem:

[image: "Print Problem"-Picture here]

Very important for me is the bottom part (with the #). You can see that it starts on the same position on the right side, but it ends differently on the left side.

Why does this happen?

I've tried many things like changing the InteractiveSize, but nothing helps.

What I need is, that both print variants (PDF and Report Viewer) look the same and have the original size and position like in the report builder.

Any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the CRM Report Viewer it uses your default printer settings in 
Windows. Try to edit your default printer settings removing margins.

best.